# Is there enough space in the US for every US teen go on a 2 week outdoors trip?

Tags: near-future, united-states

I am writing a piece of fiction that is a collection of short stories based around potential changes to the US Public School system and US policy on restricting access. (Book Title I think, Restricting Access). One story takes place in the near future, were a progressive party leader (Bull Moose Party) gets elected and establishes what he considers the second half of Roosevelt's conservation plan, making spending time in nature part of high-school curriculum. The requirement is set to ensure Young Americans (13-18) appreciate the Earth and what needs to be protected with environmental reform by taking a 2 week trip each year to various parks/ preserves.

Teens are allowed to pick their own groups, and a male and female chaperone would be required for the first few years. Students who show promise, athleticism and good character would be allowed to go on higher skill level treks without the need of a chaperone. Based on those three attributes, groups would be assigned to a trek that matches the lowest score of attributes in the group. So for example, kids who litter frequently, show poor camp skills, are generally unpleasant to chaperones or other teens, or are unable to walk for a long amount of time would be assigned to less strenuous treks, but the trek would still physically demanding (possibly trail making or a similar service based trip) and away from all electronics and modern technologies. One of the pillars of the Trek Program is that by living without toilets, stoves, sinks, etc. teens will learn to appreciate what they have when not out in the wilderness/ trail.

Is there enough space for this to exist if the program would be restricted to the US? For reference Philmont is a popular summer camp for boy-scouts and they have 22,000 people walk through their doors every year.

Comment: Hi, drawbacks to whom? The Parents who open their wallets to pay, the forest, the kids or the aliens who are attacking and abducting all the cows in India. I'm voting to put the question on hold as too broad until you can clarify what the specific worldbuilding problem is. There is a certain clarity lacking regarding what the actual issue is.

Comment: @Don I'm looking for reasons people would not want this to happen, so drawbacks to the program. Maybe an answer would be that people who want to use the trails who are not in high school would be over run with high schoolers. Maybe it would be that foresting companies don't want people getting attached to trees. I am trying to make sure I don't miss a prominent negative response when writing this piece.

Comment: Whilst I understand your concerns, this is not the site for fishing for ideas in the way you might want. We have a question, one best answer system-model here. Unfortunately your question is insufficiently constrained to fit. You can [edit] though.

Comment: @DonQualm edited the question to be specific

Comment: There are plenty of programs like this in the United States already.  Most work by staggaring the camp period over the course of a week or two among the various schools in district.  My school system, for example, made it a requirement for completion of the 6th grade, the program lasted a week and was an overnight stay.  There were usually one to two schools depending on size at a time.

Comment: *From review* I'm afraid that I don't understand what you mean by "enough space" here - without a clear definition, this all becomes opinion-based. Plus your edit has invalidated an existing answer to your question. It seems you have a few choices: Delete the question and start again, (maybe in the [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions)), you can re-edit the question to fit with your intentions, but in a way that doesn't invalidate existing answers, or you can ask another (more specific and clear) question.

Comment: @Don I tried to delete but cannot because there is an answer. I flagged the post for moderator deletion, and plan to sandbox the question when I figure out what I specifically want answered. Thanks for your help

Comment: Great, as soon as you do that I'll try to pitch-in and help.

Comment: By "trip", you mean 2 week backpacking trip (very challenging, especially for new hikers), or camping at boy scouts camp will do?

Comment: (a) This isn't a worldbuilding question.  We allow real-world questions, but only in the context of worldbuilding.  I don't see any worldbuilding here at all.  (b) After you've defined what "space" means and the requirements of the program, the result is just math.  Something along the lines of "if space = national parks & maximum density of people-per-square-mile ∴ max # of teens = X."  (c) As written, I can't vote to reopen.  If reopened as written, I'd vote to close as not about worldbuilding.

Comment: There is not really a "US Public School system." There are 50 state public school systems, and some are very different from others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Cost.**
  You mention the clerical work, but shipping the kids and giving them gear is also expensive.
- **Qualified supervisors.**
  Can the Geography or Phys Ed teachers do the job, or do you need specialists?
- **Rewarding work.**
  Are there really enough trails to blaze and cabins to stock for the "free labor" you generate?
- **Classroom time.**
  One such trip per year could cost perhaps 5% of the time spent on Maths, Literature, etc. This could be more if the trips are properly prepared and analyzed ("what will we do?" and "what went wrong?"). Add another year to school?